# Atomic Interlocked.Add taking async func as parameter

Tags: asynchronous, interlocked

I have a case where i have to implement an addition atomically and just to save a statement - i did the below

```
int result = Interlocked.Add(ref int source, await ComputeAsync(object someObj);

public async Task<int> ComputeAsync(object someObj)
{
  // some operations
  ....
}
```

Is there anything **wrong** with the above Interlocked.Add statement. Can we pass an await function which returns an int as param to the add stmt? What are the implications if any ?

Comment: Any **help** is _much_ _appreciated_

Answer (score 0):

That code would work fine, as long as you understand that `ComputeAsync` will be fully completed before `Add` is invoked. That is, the order of execution is like this:

```
int value = await ComputeAsync(someObj);
int result = Interlocked.Add(ref int source, value);
```